# Adding SQL table values to separate inner joined table values

Tags: sql, asp-classic, inner-join, addition

I am trying to get the 'pointsGiven' from one table (tableCourse), and add them to a person's current 'pointsAchieved' in a separate table (tableCoursePerson).

My current sql statement looks like this:

SQL="UPDATE TCP SET TCP.PointsAchieved=10 FROM TableCoursePerson AS TBC INNER JOIN tableCourse AS TC ON TCP.PointsId=TC.PointsID WHERE TCP.transactionID=?

At the moment, this statement is simply updating the person's points to 10 whenever they complete the course. I want to get the pointsGiven value from the TableCourse table and add them to pointsAchieved in the TableCoursePerson table in one SQL Statement.

Thanks in advance.

```
TableCourse

SessionID   PointsGiven
1           2
2           7
5           3
8           6


TableCoursePerson 

SessionID   PointsAchieved
1           0
2           0
5           0
8           0


After the SQL statement has run, the TableCoursePerson table should look like this:


SessionID   PointsAchieved
1           2
2           7
5           3
8           6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically done all the work.  Just change the `10` to the appropriate column:

```
UPDATE TCP
    SET PointsAchieved = TC.PointsGiven
    FROM TableCoursePerson AS TBC INNER JOIN 
          tableCourse AS TC
          ON TCP.PointsId = TC.PointsID
    WHERE TCP.transactionID = ?;
```

You might want this instead for the `set`:

```
SET PointsAchieved = PointsAchieved + TC.PointsGiven
```